# SQL query not returning the correct information

Tags: javascript, mysql

```
connection.query(`SELECT endTime FROM giveaway WHERE guildId = ? AND endTime < ${Date.now()} AND finished = 0`, [data.guildId, data.endTime], (err, result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Any idea why this returns `[]`?

Im completely unsure about why nothing is being retured. Everything seems right with my SQL, and database.

[image]

Comment: i think the problem could be from `Date.now()` because it has a different syntax format from the database format try to replace it with `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: When using that I get undefined back. Also, when trying this: I get an empty array too 

    `connection.query("SELECT endTime FROM giveaway WHERE guildId = ? AND finished = 0", [data.guildId, data.endTime], (err, result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })`

Comment: could you mention which database you use and the package you control it?

Comment: Sorry. I'm using mysql and hidiSQL to look at whats in the database. 
All inserts are done via mysql (not through the gui)

Comment: what about the package you use in javascript?

Comment: your second query didn't work because you pass for `finished value a `date` not a `boolean` value

Comment: Can you confirm that `data.guildId` and/or `data.endTime` return any value? Probably just do something like `console.log(data.guildId)` and see if there's a value for it? By the way, I only see 1 placeholder (`?`) in the query but you're giving it 2 values (`[data.guildId, data.endTime]`), is the latter being used at all?